# How to link all javascript workspace like Java?

Tags: javascript, java, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I want to link all javascript files in my IDE, like Java at Eclipse. I'm trying to do this in Atom or VSCode. Somethings that I need:

- I want to link my global variables and functions, sometimes I use require.js but sometimes I add all js files in my index.html;
- With Ctrl+click (or similar) I want to go to the variable/method implementation (independent if it is in the same file or not);
- When I use Ctrl+Space (or similar) after some object for exemple, I want to see all attributes inside of it.

Is it possible? Especially using Atom or VSCode?

Comment: ummmm..... You want what exactly???

Comment: Intellisense is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I want this functionality but using Atom IDE or VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Atom the atom-ternjs package (  https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs ) should provide what you are looking for.

It uses ternjs to provide autocompletion for variables and functions and allows you to go to the variable or function declaration.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for all this time. Tank you very much

Answer (score 0):

VSCode should support some Javascript Intellisense features natively. According to [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript), VSCode supports features such as Go to Definition, Find all References, and global variable completion, as well as things like linters. Hopefully this will be enough to get you started with your project!

Comment: You are right. May be I didn't know how to say what I need. I think the feature that I'm looking for is https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7929246-javascript-intellisense thank you for your answer.